# Frequencies from unsorted data

Tags: frequency

I have a 2D samples `f(x,y) = z`  in a circle (disc). Values `x, y` are not generaly uniform, but they can be resampled.

Is there a way how to obtain frequencies from this data without the knowledge of their order (basically, if I rotate the disc, the frequncies remain the same)?